# SQL Server 2008 Function Convert GMT time to AEST and also take of daylight Saving

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, gmt

I need to convert the time from GMT format to AEST (Australia) and also take care of the daylight saving properly.

Any idea or help will be appreciated.

Thanks 
Shadab

Comment: Do you mean GMT or do you mean UTC?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides a `CONVERT_TZ` function.  For this to work, the `time_zone%` tables have to be populated.

There's no need for me to repeat the MySQL documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: Sorry I was asking about SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server **2008** and newer, you can use the `DATETIMEOFFSET` datatype for date/time values including a time zone.

There's also a [`TODATETIMEOFFSET` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630335.aspx) that converts a UTC time to a timezone-based date/time.

So in your case, you could convert the UTC date/time to AEST date/time like this:

```
DECLARE @todaysDateTime datetime2;
SET @todaysDateTime = SYSUTCDATETIME();

SELECT 
    TODATETIMEOFFSET (@todaysDateTime, '+10:00'); -- AEST date/time
```

What I don't really know is whether there's anything to automagically handle daylight savings settings - you might need to handle that yourself, by defining the timezone offset (+10:00 for AEST, +11:00 for AEDT, depending on the date in the year).